# Sort an array of dictionary (swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

```
let unsorted = [{Name:Amy,age:20},{Name:Bill,age:20}]
let sortedDict = sorted(unsorted){a,b in return a.Name < b.Name}
```

How can I sort the unsorted array according to the Name key? Above code seems doesn't work.

Comment: is the array only 2 indexes or is this just an example? Because if it's longer than this you'd want to implement a `for` loop to sort the array as it goes through the indexes

Comment: I think you're missing some here, it can't be a dictionary because in your case have repeated keys `Name` for example and your code of course not compile at all. Can you clarify better your question please?

Comment: its an example, var array : [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]  . the array is like this. i want to sort according to key Name

Answer (score 1):

Your sorting syntax works (almost) if you are using a custom struct rather than a dictionary

```
struct Person {
  let name : String
  let age : Int
}

let unsortedPeople = [Person(name:"Bill", age:20), Person(name:"Amy", age:20)]
```

Now you can use the `sorted` function

```
let sortedDict = unsortedPeople.sorted{ $0.name < $1.name }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary in your question is wrong, so I am assuming you have a dictionary like

```
let unsorted = ["Amy": Amy, "Dan": Dan, "Ben": Ben]
```

If so, you can sort by

```
let sorted = unsorted.sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }
```

Comment: i have edited the dictionary above. can you make use of that and suggest an answer for that? thank you.