# Sort an array of dictionaries by a certain key value (Swift 3)

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I was looking for a way to sort an array of invoice dictionaries based on invoice ID (which is a value of one of the keys in the dictionary). I couldn't find a solution that worked as well as I would've liked so I wrote out a function which works well for me and I thought I'd share it with the community.

It's pretty simple, you just pass in the array, pass in the key to sort it by and it returns the array sorted.

```
let testArray: Array<Dictionary<String, String>> = sortDictArrayByKey(arr: someUnsortedArray, key: keyToSort)
```

```objc
func sortDictArrayByKey(arr: Array<Dictionary<String, String>>, key: String) -> Array<Dictionary<String, String>>{
    var keyArray = Array<String>()
    var usedKeys = Array<String>()
    for object in arr{
        keyArray.append(object[key]!)
    }

    keyArray.sort(by: <)

    var newArray = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()
    for keyVal in keyArray{

    // Check if we've already seen this entry, if so, skip it
        if usedKeys.contains(keyVal){
            continue
        }
        usedKeys.append(keyVal)

    // Check for duplicate entries
        var tempArray = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()
        for object in arr{
            if object[key] == keyVal{
                tempArray.append(object)
            }
        }
        for item in tempArray{
            newArray.append(item)
        }
        tempArray.removeAll()
    }
    return newArray
}
```

Comment: If you want to do a self Q&A – you need to format it like one (i.e have an actual question, and then post your solution as an answer to that question). Although that being said, I'm sure there's a duplicate Q&A out there for this, that you could post your solution as an answer to (http://stackoverflow.com/q/40050495/2976878, http://stackoverflow.com/q/39865278/2976878).

Comment: Although that all being said, the solution itself seems unnecessarily complicated – unless I'm missing something, you'd achieve the same result with `return arr.sorted(by: { $0[key]! < $1[key]! })`. I also have a suspicion that you should probably be dealing with an array of a given structure rather than an array of dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Extension

You can created an extension available for `Arrays` of `Dictionaries` where both the `Key` and the `Value` are `String(s)`.

```
extension Array where Element == [String:String] {
    func sorted(by key: String) -> [[String:String]] {
        return sorted { $0[key] ?? "" < $1[key] ?? "" }
    }
}
```

### Example

```
let crew = [
    ["Name":"Spook"],
    ["Name":"McCoy"],
    ["Name":"Kirk"]
]

crew.sorted(by: "Name")

// [["Name": "Kirk"], ["Name": "McCoy"], ["Name": "Spook"]]
```

Comment: Of course, the extension isn't necessary; you can just call `arr.sorted { $0[key] ?? "" < $1[key] ?? "" }`

Comment: @BallpointBen Thanks to the extension you are sure you are sorting an `Array` of `Dictionaries` of type `[String:String]` as requested in the question

Comment: If you just call the method on an arbitrary array, it will only compile if the array is of the right type anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this. Good call. I love extensions.